# Ganache -f how can I fork the whole chain?

Tags: ganache-cli

Im developing locally but I need a full copy, Im using ganache for local dev, also providing -f option to fork another blockchain (BSC), is it possible to download the complete chain somehow?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that binance smart chain network enable ganache-cli commands...try..

ganache-cli -f https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org