# How to fork the binance chain?

Tags: ganache-cli, bsc

How can I have a local copy of the binance chain for use in ganache like to use BNB as default coin instead ETH?

I see here [Ganache -f how can I fork the whole chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97029/ganache-f-how-can-i-fork-the-whole-chain) that I must provide -f parameter but I don't know exactly how.

By the way... I need a CLI flavor because I'm using Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binance provide [instructions](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html) how to run a full node. Then you can enable http requests and use the localhost endpoint with ganache to fork it.

There's [`ganache-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache-cli) that is headless.

Comment: Well I don't want to be part of Binance Chain as a full node. Can you explain a little more? Can I fork an already running node of somebody else?

Comment: @MagnoC Check BSC documentation https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html for access to public RPC endpoints. Just be aware they are public so they have some restrictions like how many queries you can make.

Comment: Sorry but I realy need a LOCAL Binance Chain. I don't want someone put they hands on my contracts before I finish my ideas.

Comment: @MagnoC It doesn't seem BSC support light clients, so the only options are to run a full node or use an RPC provider. In any case when using ganache with fork option it will deploy your contract locally.

Comment: I think BSC was a fork from Ethereum therefore having same methods... I'll try it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

it's seems ganache-cli suport forking bsc network.

```
ganache-cli -f https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/nih0zx/how_to_fork_bsc_mainet/gz3vhex?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 0):

You can get Json RPC Endpoint from from nodereal.io

https://bsc-mainnet.nodereal.io/v1/<API_KEY>

Answer (score 0):

```
Speedrun Solution: Let's go
```

1. Get your RPC Endpoint ([I prefer QuickNode for BSC](https://quicknode.com))
2. Download and configure `ganache-cli` [Github](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli-archive)
3. Follow this Guide, and you're good.

---

After testing it like that, I recommend running it in Docker.
[Check out this Guide:](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/run-the-ganache-cli-inside-the-docker-container-5e70bc962bfe)

And also, add a custom Explorer ("Etherscan for your Fork") with either [Blocscout](https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/manual-deployment) or [Ethernal](https://tryethernal.com/).

Happy Hacking & have fun